# Cannot get the value from input field onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flexslider

I have an input field to enter the email in one of the slides of a flex slider. I couldn't get the value from the input field on the onclick of the adjacent button. I have tried .val(), .html() and .text(). Yes, I know .val() has to be used for getting typed in text but why doesn't it work? Everything returns an empty string, even in the console.

This is the input field

```
<input id="newsletterEmail" type="email" style="margin-right:10px;">
<input id="newsletterSubscription" type="button" value="Subscribe"  onclick="subscribeNewsletter();">
```

I tried getting the value

```
$('#newsletterEmail').val()
```

I am appending the slider dynamically based on a condition. I am getting the value correclty when I put in the HTML initialy, so I guess the issue is with adding the contents. I have used delegate/on to access the dynamic button, but is there any such special cases to get the value from an input field. I am adding the contents as a string as below :

```
    var sliderContent = '<div class="flexslider" id="banner_slider"><ul class="slides"><li id="simple_banner"><div class="loginHolder containerBanner clearfix"><div class="leftContent"><img id="homePageHeroImage" class="img-responsive logoBanner1 bannerSliderImg" src="/assets/Logo_banner1.png" alt="Logo_banner1"><p id="logoContent">Why drive for it?</p><p class="centralize" id="stretchContent">The premium products you need are just a few clicks away!</p><div class="loginButtons"><input id="loginBut" type="button" value="Login"onClick="window.open("http://app.grasspit.com","_target");" style="margin-right:10px;"><input id="signBut" type="button" value="Sign Up"onClick="window.open("http://app.grasspit.com/?page=signup","target");"></div><p class="mobileImage"><img class="img-responsive" src="/assets/Mobile.png" alt="Mac-and-iPhone"></p></div><div class="rightContent"><img class="img-responsive" src="/assets/Mac-and-iPhone.png" alt="Mac-and-iPhone"></div></div></li><li id="newsletter_banner"><div class="loginHolder containerBanner clearfix newsCont"><div class="leftContent"><img class="img-responsive logoBanner2 bannerSliderImg" src="/assets/newsLetter_logo.png" alt="News Letter Logo"><p id="logoContent">Subscribe to Grassp Newsletter</p><p class="centralize" id="stretchContent">to get updates for new products, new locations and special promotions.</p><div class="loginButtons"><input id="newsletterEmail" type="email" style="margin-right:10px;"><input id="newsletterSubscription" type="button" value="Subscribe"></div></div></div></li></ul></div>';
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have another element with the same id as 'newsletterEmail'?

Comment: Any console errors? Works for me : http://jsfiddle.net/zPK36/

Comment: Your code is correct, `.val()` is the correct method for this so you must have an error elsewhere in your document/javascript.

Comment: Looks like you need to show us more of your code, as this is working.

Comment: Works here as well.  Could it possibly be a browser issue?  That or an error in your js.

Comment: No identical id's. And no console errors. :( To give more info..I am appending the contents including the slider to a div based on a condition. Is it because that it is dynamically added?

Comment: Try using delegated click event instead of `onclick`

Comment: Tried it..but no avail

Comment: Please add more code... more javascript part... so that we can look at the scope of input `.val()` as well...

Comment: Can you provide code in a [JSFiddle?](http://jsfiddle.net/)